# Can I load calculated measures from SSAS cube in Power Query?

Tags: excel, business-intelligence, msbi, powerquery

Power Query Version 2.17 is supporting SSAS Cubes as data source now. When I connect to a cube I just see the standard measures of the cube and not the calculated members defined in the cube. Is there a way in Power Query to get access to the calculated members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in version 2.17 is, that you can just query calculated measures that are assigned to a measure group.
See [Chris Webb's BI Blog](https://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2014/11/25/power-query-now-works-with-ssas/) for further informations.

In Version 2.18 this is fixed.